# How to prove that the inverse of following matrix exist and has integer entries?

Tags: matrices, inverse

How to prove that the following matrix has an inverse with integer entries? Also find out the inverse.

\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & \frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{3} & \cdots &\  \frac{1}{n-1} & \frac{1}{n} \\
\frac{1}{2} & \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{4} & \cdots &\  \frac{1}{n} & \frac{1}{n+1} \\
 \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{5} & \cdots &\  \frac{1}{n+1} & \frac{1}{n+2} \\
\frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{5} & \cdots &\  \frac{1}{n+1} & \frac{1}{n+2} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots\\
\frac{1}{n} & \frac{1}{n+1} & \frac{1}{n+2} & \cdots &\  \frac{1}{2n-2} & \frac{1}{2n-1} \\
  \end{bmatrix}

Comment: As written, it has no inverse, because you duplicated a line 

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the question is about the matrix $A$ whose $(i,j)$ entry is $A_{ij}=\frac{1}{i+j-1}$. (As remarked in the comments, there is a typo as written in the question.)

I claim that $A^{-1}$ has the following explicit formula:
$$
\left(A^{-1}\right)_{ij}=(-1)^{i+j}\binom{n+i-1}{n-j}\binom{n+j-1}{n-i}\binom{i+j-2}{i-1}^2(i+j-1).
$$

To verify that this is indeed the inverse, I would suggest using induction to show that its product with $A$ is the identity matrix.

Comment: It perhaps would be way more interesant if you could at least show a link or some reasoning on **how** was that formula for the inverse *deduced* ...

Comment: I spotted the pattern...